# Use Class Member Function Pointer before Class Definition C++

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I have the following code:

```c
// FILE_NAME: compiler.h

typedef enum Precedence { /* ENUM MEMBERS */ } Precedence;
typedef enum TokenType { /* ENUM MEMBERS */ } TokenType;

typedef void (Compiler::*ParseFn)();

typedef struct ParseRule {
    ParseFn prefix;
    ParseFn infix;
    Precedence precedence;
} ParseRule;

class Compiler {
    public:
        std::unordered_map<TokenType, ParseRule> rules;
        ParseRule getRule(TokenType type) {
            return rules[type];
        };
        void binary();
        void unary();
};
```

I am trying to define a hashmap that maps a key of `TokenType` to a value that has the form of the struct `ParserRule`.

An example of a key-value pair for the `Compiler::rules` hashmap is as follows:

```c
rules[TOKEN_MINUS] = {unary, binary, PREC_TERM}
```

When I try to compile with C++11, I get the following error, plus many others:

```
./compiler/compiler.h:58:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Compiler'
typedef void (Compiler::*ParseFn)();
```

This makes sense since I am trying to use the class `Compiler` to define the type `ParseFn` before the `Compiler` class has been defined.

I am very new to coding in C/C++ (I started learning a couple of weeks ago), so I was wondering if there is another way of defining the types and classes without causing a compiler error.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but in C++ you don’t have to do the `typedef enum Precedence { ... } Precedence;` dance. That’s a C thing. In C++, `enum Precedence { ... };` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to (pre-)declare `Compiler` as a class before referring to it:

```
class Compiler;

typedef void (Compiler::*ParseFn)();
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I thought of doing that many times, but it just felt like I was declaring the class twice, which I imagined would throw an error.

Comment: You can _declare_ things as many times as you want, as long as the declarations match. You can _define_ them only once.